# Accessing Fantom class' members from a member function in a constructor it-block?

Tags: fantom

If I define this Fantom class

```
const class Mixed
{
  const Int whole
  const Int numerator
  const Int denominator

  const | -> Int[]| convertToFrac

  new make( |This| func ) { func( this ) }
}
```

And I want to create an instance defining the convertToFrac function, like this:

```
class Example
{
  Void main( Str args )
  {
    mixed := Mixed {
      whole = 2
      numerator = 3
      denominator = 8
      convertToFrac = |->Int[]| {
        return [ whole * denominator + numerator, denominator ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler complains saying:

- `Unknown variable 'numerator'`
- `Unknown variable 'denominator'`
- `Unknown variable 'whole'`

Is there any way to refer to the object "mixed" being created from within the function "convertToFrac", also being defined, without passing the "mixed" object as a parameter of the function?

If I prepend each variable with "mixed", like so:

```
return [ mixed.whole * mixed.denominator + mixed.numerator, mixed.denominator ]
```

The compiler complains: `Unknown variable 'mixed'`.

Using `this.whole` doesn't make sense as it refers to the Example class.
Using `it.whole` doesn't make sense either as it refers to the Function.

Can anyone please suggest the way to access the "mixed" object from within the "convertToFrac" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly assessed, the issue is that you're using an `it-block` inside an `it-block`, and because you're using an implicit `it` (i.e. you're don't have any `it` qualifiers) there is confusion as to what's being referenced.

I'll write out the `it` qualifiers out long hand so you can see what's going on:

```java
mixed := Mixed {
    // 'it' is the Mixed instance
    it.whole = 2
    it.numerator = 3
    it.denominator = 8

    it.convertToFrac = |->Int[]| {
        // 'it' is now the func param

        // 'it.whole' doesn't exist, because there is no func param
        return [ it.whole * it.denominator + it.numerator, it.denominator ]
    }
}
```

Your idea of using the `mixed` variable qualifier was a good one but, unfortunately, whilst processing the ctor the `mixed` variable hasn't been created yet so can't be referenced.

But you can create your own `mixed` variable in the it-block, and the following compiles and runs quite happily:

```java
mixed := Mixed {
    // 'mixed' doesn't exist here yet, because we're still creating a value to assign to it
    it.whole = 2
    it.numerator = 3
    it.denominator = 8

    // assign `it` to our own `mixed` variable
    mixed := it
    it.convertToFrac = |->Int[]| {
        // use our own `mixed` variable
        return [ mixed.whole * mixed.denominator + mixed.numerator, mixed.denominator ]
    }
}
```